# Files are getting corrupted after upload

Tags: javascript, filezilla, css, hosting

I am using Filezilla to send files to my webserver. But I have some issues. When I send the file to my webserver the file gets corrupted.

Here is the file that I upload:

[image]

After upload the file looks like:

[image]

Can someone tell my why I have this issue and how I can prevent that the files are getting corrupted?

The files that are getting corrupted are mostly `.js` and `.css` files.